# Is there an optimal time of day and/or weather conditions for weeding?

Tags: weed-control, weather

I'm talking here about a quickfire weeding session (probably with a hoe) where you haven't time to do anything much about carting away the weed debris.

I'm assuming mid-morning in full sun is optimum, because there's time for the heat to kill the weed debris and prevent it reestablishing.

Or are there other considerations?

Comment: Sun makes sense. Rain might have the opposite effect. So look at the forecast or be aware of local patterns - eg. Some places you can set your watch by the afternoon rain!

Comment: Early morning might be even better -- especially if the soil is damp. Hoeing in dry soil makes a mess; when it's wet the weeds chop out easily. And the debris has more time to dry out (assuming a sunny day) and die.

Answer (score 10):

Because my garden is underneath a street light, I like to weed at night.

[Farmers take advantage](http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m1200/is_n8_v142/ai_12514744/) of messing with their dirt at night because the weeds in their soil that are turned over are less likely to germinate.

Here are some other advantages.

1. Less mosquitoes than at dusk.
2. You can meet the toads who roam your garden at night.
3. No sunburn.
4. You have an excuse for mistaking your radishes for weeds.

Comment: I agree ... choose a time based on what fits you better, not what's better for the weeds.  I find the heat of mid-day makes for a better excuse to have a couple of cold beers nearby.

Comment: I find the weed are much easier to pull in the day or so following a heavy rain.